Combing multiplicative and additive effects in GAMs or GLMs
I am currently modelling a data set of house sales prices, P, as a function of various characteristics such as location, house size etc. etc. The list of explanatory variables can be divided into two categories:
a) Location-characteristics x (determining the value, L, of the lot of the property): coordinates, distance to coast, etc. etc.
b) Building characteristics y (determining the value, B, of the building of the property): condition of house, age etc. etc.
Now, based on the above I would like to fit a model of the form:
$
P(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) = L(\textbf{x}) + B(\textbf{y}) \ \ \ (1)
$
However, as I am modelling a strictly positive variable (house price), my approach so far has been to use a log-link coupled with a Gamma distribution. While this does seem to be a commonly adapted approach in literature the obvious downside is that it  forces a multiplicative relationship between the response and the covariates, which is not compatible with the additive form in (1). Ideally I would like my model to be of the form, which is multiplicative in $L(\textbf{x})$ and additive in $B(\textbf{y})$, i.e. something like:
$
P(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) = \Pi_{i}s(x_{i}) + \sum_{i}s(y_{i}) \ \ \ (2)
$
What are my possibilities (if any) for fitting this type of model structure using either GAMs or GLMs?
